# Every time when I open SQL Server client, it asks for server name

Tags: sql-server

Every time when I open SQL Server client, it asks for server name. Is there any way I can save the server name forever?

Thanks in advance,

Nishant Khanna

Comment: Just to be clear when you say sql server client you mean sql server management studio?

Comment: You have to ask the developer of the client application.

Comment: @P.Salmon Yes, I mean sql server management studio only

Answer (score 0):

SSMS has a [registered servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/register-servers/register-servers) feature that allows you to save server names with login credentials and organize them into groups. Select View-->Registered Servers (or press Ctrl-Alt-G) to bring up the list of registered servers. Expand the Registered Servers node and right-click to create new groups and registrations.

Once registered, you can open a new query window or Object Explorer in the context of that server with a right-click.

SSMS startup behavior may be customized from Tools-->Options-->Environment-->Startup.